# Update first match row

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I need to update table B based on table A aggregation.
The relation from table A aggregation to table B is 1:M , But i want to update just one matching row from B (it can be any row from the "many").

```
update B set spent = aggregation.spent
from 
(select provider_id,sum(spent) spent from A group by provider_id) aggregation
where B.provider_id = aggregation.provider_id
```

adding limit is not leggal.

At the end only one of the matching record from B need to be with the updated spent.

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  provider_id bigint,
  channel int,
  spent int
 );

CREATE TABLE B
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  provider_id bigint,
  spent int
 );

insert into A values (1,1,1,1);
insert into A values (2,1,2,1);
insert into B values (1,1,0);
insert into B values (2,1,0);
```

Comment: Can I ask you why *it can be any row from the "many"*? This sounds strange, it means you don't have any control on the updated records, and there is no cryteria used to choose the record to update? I can't figure out what kind of database design would need such a thing.

Comment: This is done as a one time migration process from old table to new ones. table B is used for report so i aggregated before report is served , so i want that one of the record for this provider will have the migration spent. Alternative can be to split the spent from old table divided by provider record in the new table.

Comment: I'm sorry, the more I try to understand, the more I fail to :) I just can't imagine why you would to that, it seems like something is missing here and can lead to a data corruption. A pl/pgsql function is what comes to my mind, but still I don't get the reasons. Maybe you could provide an example of `before and after` the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/abada/3)

```
update B set spent = s.spent
from
    (
        select distinct on (provider_id)
            be.id, aggregation.spent
        from
            (
                select provider_id, sum(spent) spent
                from A
                group by provider_id
            ) aggregation
            inner join
            B be using (provider_id)
    ) s    
where B.id = s.id
```

Comment: I wanst familiar with distinct on... Great!!!! By the way is there a way to give an alias to the table in the update clause ?